# Reading string between two indices without copying

Tags: c#

C# has a substring method that copies the characters with respect to given start index and possibly length parameter.

However, let's say we are dealing with millions of requests and each request needs to perform an operation on some part of a string. Further, assume that this operation is not making any changes in string, but just reads part of it. **I certainly do not want to copy and use extra memory.**

Is there way to achieve making this operation without copying?

The operation can be as simply as the following:

```
if (someReadOperation(this.request["some-header"].substring(10, 20)))
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

**UPDATE**
Let's say `someReadOperation` reads the string and checks if it exists in some dictionary or it is equal to some other string.

Comment: Have you tried dealing with these millions of requests and was there a performance issue?

Comment: Let the garbage collector do the job. If you don't store the strings for a long time (f.e. as variable in the scope of a loop) you should not care about memory consumption.

Comment: If you're dealing with millions of request chances are you'll be I/O bound way before a string compare will bind you. Also, you can work with byte arrays. Also, what server are you using?

Comment: I agree with the comments above. If you must handle the string directly, you can always index into it like an array of char.

Comment: Tempted to suggest the 'unsafe' pointers...

Comment: Why would you choose to pick specific parts and skip the main question? I said I look for the ways to figure out not to copy string and use extra memory.

Comment: Your question is too vague, because the answer specifically depends on what the read operation does.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following alternative to do the required operation...

```
if (this.request["some-header"].Length > 10)
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using an [ArraySegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type to track the fragments without having to allocate space for each portion of the string buffer. This will avoid the copying you wish to avoid.

You do need to be careful in that the class exposes the shared underlying array with some properties/methods.